# DateTimeOffset daily incremental number

Tags: c#, sql-server, timezone, timezone-offset, datetimeoffset

Consider I have an application executed on a server farm with timezone offset: `-06:00`. But the user interface shows only dates with `+02:00` offset. I used `DateTimeOffset` in C# and `DateTimeOffset(0)` in SQL Server (`2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4505224) - 14.0.2027.2 (X64)`)

Consider that you are executing the following code on the server:

```
var now = DateTimeOffset.Now;
var start = new DateTimeOffset(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 0, 0, 0, 0, now.Offset); // Offset `-06:00`
var end = start.AddDays(1);

return await connection.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>(
    "SELECT ISNULL(MAX(IncrementalNumber) + 1, 1) " +
    "FROM Forms.Trips " +
    "WHERE UserId = @userId " +
    "   AND CreationDate >= @start AND CreationDate < @end",
    new { userId, start, end });
```

The goal of that code is to get a per user **daily** incremental number. But I found two weird records with **both** `IncrementalNumber` set to `1`:

```
2020-07-26 23:50:33 -06:00 -- (2020-07-27 07:50:33 +02:00 in the user interface offset)
2020-07-27 02:09:48 -06:00 -- (2020-07-27 10:09:48 +02:00 in the user interface offset)
```

The problem is that in the user interface, where I convert every server date to +02:00 offset in the presentation layer, those dates are referring to the same day (27th of july), so I was expecting they would be associated to a different incremental number, 1 and 2.

This is my presentation layer offset conversion:

```
private static readonly TimeZoneInfo _italianTimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");

public static DateTime ToItalianTimestamp(DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset)
{
    var utc = dateTimeOffset.ToUniversalTime().DateTime;
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utc, _italianTimeZoneInfo);
}
```

Where am I getting wrong? How can I generate a per user daily incremental number that will be **daily** also in the `+02:00` offset?

Comment: Shouldn't `start` and `end` be in the destination offset? It seems like you want all records in `Trips` with a `CreationTime` between `2020-07-27 00:00:00 +02:00` and `2020-07-27 23:59:59 +02:00`. But, your query is pulling all records in `Trips` with a `CreationTime` between `2020-07-27 00:00:00 -06:00` and `2020-07-27 23:59:59 -06:00`.

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson I think your is the correct answer!